Postgres redeployment on EKS pulls old Postgres deployment seemingly saved on EC2 nodes storage
I'm trying to deploy an ephemeral postgres database for our development team to bring up and down without persisting any data. Currently during testing I'm using kubectl apply -f postgres deployment of the following items.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-secret
  namespace: dev-cs
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
 
 #---

 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: dev-cs
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: 'postgres:latest'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-secret
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgresdata
      volumes:
        - name: postgresdata
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-volume-claim

#---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume-claim
  namespace: dev-cs
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: gp2
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi

#---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume
  namespace: dev-cs
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: gp2
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/postgresql

#---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  #namespace: dev-cs
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres

I'm getting this error, and from googling it looks like the PV is not getting blown away after deleting the deployment.
2024-07-10 16:19:43.989 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.12 (Debian 14.12-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-07-10 16:19:43.989 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-07-10 16:19:43.989 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-07-10 16:19:43.992 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-07-10 16:19:43.995 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-07-09 16:33:32 UTC
2024-07-10 16:19:43.996 UTC [26] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/16FE650: wanted 24, got 0
2024-07-10 16:19:43.996 UTC [26] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2024-07-10 16:19:43.996 UTC [26] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record

I have tried kubectl delete -f postgres and redeploying a few times with postgres:14 and postgres:latest.
My thought is that the pv is re-using the same portion of memory on the ec2 node itself, as when I run the pv/pvc AWS is not provisioning a new ebs volume but seemingly using the same node ebs root volume attached to the ec2 node.

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume-claim
  ...
spec:
  storageClassName: gp2 # <--
...
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      name: postgresdata  # <--
  volumes:
  - name: postgresdata  # <--
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: postgres-volume-claim

You are using EBS as you database storage in your spec.

...an ephemeral postgres database

You can use emptyDir. hostPath is a more advance use of storage which involve the file system on the host. Just change your volumes will do:
volumes:
- name: postgresdata
  emptyDir: {}

No other PVC/PV required. You get fresh volume every time you start a new pod, the volume automatically remove every time you delete the pod.

Changing from hostpath and adding a StorageClass provisioner or aws-ebs worked. Thank you!

The behavior you describe is exactly what a hostPath: type volume does.  On whichever node the Pod happens to be scheduled on, it uses that directory on the host.  If a Pod gets deleted and recreated on another node, the old data will be, well, misplaced at least; if a second Pod gets created on the original node, it will find the older data directory.
Unless you're writing something like a log aggregator that runs as a DaemonSet on every node, you should almost never use a hostPath: volume.
In most Kubernetes installations, you also don't need to manually create PersistentVolumes.  In EKS, if you create a PersistentVolumeClaim, the cluster will automatically create a PersistentVolume backed by an EBS volume.  The cluster itself is capable of detaching the EBS volume from one node and reattaching it to another, so if the Pod is deleted and recreated somewhere else, the data will follow it.
In your setup, it might be enough to delete the manual PersistentVolume.  (You may also have to delete and recreate the PersistentVolumeClaim, and you may have to delete any extant Pods as well.)  You don't seem to explicitly refer to the manually-created PersistentVolume.
Also consider using a StatefulSet here, and including the PVC setup in its volumeClaimTemplates: field.  Since multiple replicas of a PostgreSQL database can't share a data store, if you ever do wind up with more than one replica, you'll need a separate PVC for each, which a StatefulSet can do automatically.

I wasn't aware of what hostPath: actually did, added a StorageClass and removed hostPath and it worked!
